# Rails issue with parsing date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, rufus-scheduler

I have datetime strings that are outputted in the following format:

```
03/27/2014 07:52:47 PM
```

I'm using a gem called rufus-scheduler, which takes strings in a YYYY-mm-dd hh-MM-ss #### (#### is timezone offset). Are there any easy ways to convert the first string I had to a string in the format rufus-scheduler likes?

I know that one way I could do it would be to create a method that parsed the string so I could create a new datetime object from it, and then call a strftime in the format rufus likes, but I was wondering if there were any more efficient ways to go about solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::strptime` to parse, and `DateTime#strftime` to format it again.

First `require 'date'` and then:

```
2.0.0-p451 :021 > DateTime.strptime("03/27/2014 07:52:47 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S %z")
 => "2014-03-27 19-52-47 +0000"
```

Comment: Was not aware of the parse method. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Time.strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

Also, http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/ is an awesome tool for this.

Comment: Do you mean I could call Time.strftime("03/27/2014 07:52:47 PM", "%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S%z") and it wouldn't care that the first argument was a string? It could convert it for me?

Comment: No, you would need a Time object. Looks like raviolicode has a good option. I was assuming you already had a Time object that you could call the strftime method on.

Answer (score 1):

Chronic (https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) is your friend

```
require 'chronic'

p Chronic.parse('03/27/2014 07:52:47 PM')
```